# Debug .Net Winforms Application on the client

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, debugging, remote-debugging

How can I attach a debugger to my own .Net Winform application to set breakpoints, watch variables and inspect problems on client machine?

Long story:
  I have to figure out the problems with respect to client on the phone (remotely) for my current job. But I can't even find the correct form.

We have nearly 50 projects and they usually have 20 or more forms and use some 3rd party APIs. Client request may have related to crashed application or results are calculated incorrectly. So I have to figure out problem on the phone.

My idea is create a base winform, make all forms to extend that form, attach a debugger, activate that debugger with a key stroke on the client machine. Then I need to see the code, set breakpoints, watch variables and use something like immediate window to execute codes. That way I don't need to change code because of inheritance.

How can I achieve this?

PS : We have fairly good update procedure. So updating the application on the client is easy.

PS2: I will update a Debug build for my purpose.

PS3: VS Remote Debug is not an option.

PS4: Eurokelog or anything like that is not an option.

PS5: We use screen sharing application so I can view client desktop or server.

Comment: Give them a debug build and use visual studio's "Attach to Running Process"

Comment: ILSpy is not a debugger.

Comment: Damn, it's Friday, I'm at work, and now you've got me thinking about games consoles... but seriously, it sounds like you either need VS on a machine that can demonstrate the issue (unlikely by the sounds of it), or have the remote machine run the [VS remote debugging tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) and attach to them (again, not always possible if you cannot network to the remote PC).

Comment: Read up on Intellitrace. You will need to install a collector on the client machine. While running you have the user recreate the bug. It generates a file you can open in VS and debug against like a recorded playback. You must have the same build in VS as the client is running.

Comment: VS Remote debug is not an option but I will investigate Intellitrace. I hope it may also help to resolve calculation problems.